# Apache spark: cache dataframe before broadcast or not

Tags: apache-spark, caching, broadcast

can anyone explain what it happens behind the scenes and if it is better to cache the dataframe before doing a broadcast or not ?
take into consideration that this is happening on 30+ nodes

Answer (score 0):

[Caching](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.spark.cache.html) is used when you have multiple actions on the same dataframe, which could speed up the calculations (10x faster) instead of recompute the dataframe for each action. This is mainly used on iterative algorithms, so if there is only one action, then there is no benefit from caching the dataframe.

[Broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html) is mainly used to send a read only copy of the dataframe to workers instead of sending it with each task, also Spark distributes broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

These are quite two different operations, and each operation represents a solution to a different problem, so I think there is no clear effect of caching before broadcast.

Comment: yes, but basicaly when your caching, your partitions goes to the memory (serialized or not). when you re broadcasting the partitions goes to each executor, very true. my question is that if df is cached ... is an overhead  so the steps will be 1. cache (serliaze) to memory 2. deserialize from  memory . 3. send to workers.  OR  the steps will be  1. cache. 2. send serialize data to workers

Comment: I'd say the data is loaded in memory first either in case of caching or to be broadcasted, the difference in caching is that we keep the partitions in memory/disk as we expect to be used for another action, but tbh I'm not aware of the overhead of the serialization and deserialization if it was already cached, since it is also depends if the cache is serialized or not